# After implementing topic modelling of a text file I am getting similar words to describe all the topics and the results are inaccurate.

Tags: python-2.7, lda, topic-modeling

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from stop_words import get_stop_words
from gensim import corpora, models 
import gensim
import os
from os import path
from time import sleep

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
en_stop = set(get_stop_words('en'))
with open(os.path.join('c:\users\kaila\jobdescription.txt')) as f:
    Reader = f.read()


texts = unicode(Reader, errors='replace')
tdm = []

#Converted all the text to lowercase for uniform analysis
raw = texts.lower()
#Tokenized the text to individual terms and created the stop list
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in en_stop]
tdm.append(stopped_tokens)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tdm)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(i) for i in tdm]
sleep(3)
#Implemented the LdaModel
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=10, id2word = dictionary)
print(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=5, num_words=8))
```

The issue is my result has similar words to describe all the topics and the probabilities are way too low. Is there anything I am doing wrong? If anyone can assist me in yielding better results it will be great.

The following is my result:

**(0, u'0.019*will + 0.010*experience + 0.009*accounts + 0.009*finance + 0.008*accounting + 0.008*financial + 0.008*team + 0.007*reporting'), (4, u'0.016*will + 0.009*finance + 0.009*experience + 0.008*management + 0.008*accounting + 0.007*role + 0.007*financial + 0.007*work'), (7, u'0.017*will + 0.013*experience + 0.012*finance + 0.008*role + 0.008*financial + 0.007*accounting + 0.007*accounts + 0.007*years'), (2, u'0.019*will + 0.011*experience + 0.010*finance + 0.008*role + 0.007*business + 0.007*accounts + 0.007*reporting + 0.007*work'), (5, u'0.013*will + 0.011*finance + 0.011*experience + 0.009*financial + 0.008*management + 0.008*accounting + 0.008*role + 0.007*please')**

Answer (score 0):

No you are not doing anything wrong but you are misinterpreting the output. LDA generates a probability distribution for all the dictionary words under each topic. The number of topic is equal to your desired number of topic. Here the answer you provided seems logical for me since you have printed the topic 5 topics and the topic 8 words under each topic with their probability values. By the way, probability values can be very small, don't worry about that.

One possible reason for this output can be: the dataset used to train the LDA model is not diverse enough, so the top words under several topics are almost the same which also represents that the topics inferred are very close to each other. If you are expecting diversified topics, then you need a well representative data for desired number of topics.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. It was very helpful as I can now work to make my data more diversified for better results.